# How to refresh piechart in c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have made a method including the code of pie chart and call that method everywhere i need to refresh the chart, but whenever i click on those buttons where i have called the method then the pie chart duplicates the value automatically. And also i have tried Refresh() and Update option too but it doesn't work.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        chart();
    }
    private void chart()
    {
        chart1.Series["new"].Points.AddXY("Peter", "1000");
        chart1.Series["new"].Points.AddXY("Julia", "1000");
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        chart();
    }
}
```

Comment: You have static value. How do you want to refresh it?

Comment: at time of refresh 1st clear the chart object

Comment: Clear your existing Series before adding more points

Comment: try ResetAutoValues() , update()

Comment: clearing the chart object gives an exception :-An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.dll

Additional information: A chart element with the name 'new' could not be found in the 'SeriesCollection'.

Comment: The command is `chart1.Series["new"].Points.Clear();` __not__ `chart1.Series.Clear();`

Comment: Thank you so much it worked !!!

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood the problem correctly, I think you simply need to clear down the Series' Points collection.

For example:

```
        private void chart()
    {
        chart1.Series["new"].Points.Clear();
        chart1.Series["new"].Points.AddXY("Peter", "1000");
        chart1.Series["new"].Points.AddXY("Julia", "1000");
    }
```

Is this what you were looking to do?